# Vehicle Glass Image Warping Issue

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, glass

I am currently working on a Lamborghini as an assignment, and while I was working on the textures for previewing, I encountered an issue with the glass. For some reason, the objects in the interior have their position and shape warped by the glass, as seen in the example below.

[image: Perspective View of Car in Wireframe Mode]
[image: Perspective View of Car in Quick Render]

Another issue this causes is that when there are multiple windows within view, the parts of the interior objects don't appear as if they would actually connect to eachother.

[image: Connection Issue In Quick Render]

So far, I have tried adjusting the lights, adding thickness to the glass (which didn't work, so I removed it), and altering the material for the glass, but nothing I've done so far has worked. I'll provide my node setup for the glass below, and you can download the blend file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bNqc2oEw0bCRUWfDjDuyg1i2ySVmilif/view?usp=sharing'). Thanks for the help!

[image: Node Setup For Glass Material]

Comment: index of refraction (IOR) should be closer to 1.33

Comment: Thanks! Still didn't fix the issue though :(

Comment: If you just plug in the glass shader to the surface do you still get alot of distortion? the closer the IOR is to 1 the less distortion you should get.

Comment: Yes, the issue remained with glass shader being directly connected to the material output, but I lowered the IOR even further and the warping issue seems to have been fixed, although the glass looks less realistic. I'm going to read the duplicate real quick and see if that fixes my issue.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to apply my scale. Thanks for the link, and thanks for the advice with the IOR! ^-^